# How do I compare the content of a Ruby array and hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a Ruby array with content like this:

```
my_array
=> ["MPA5534285", "MPA5534555", "MPA553asdf5", "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5"]
```

I have a Ruby hash like this:

```
1.9.2p290 :012 > hash
 => {"MPA5534555"=>"something", "MPA553sf"=>"something", "MPA55345asdf5adfads"=>"something", "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5"=>"something"}
```

I need to compare the array to the hash and find where there no corresponding matches.

For example, in my array I have "MPA5534555" which, if I look in the hash, the key does exist. But, in the array "MPA5534285" doesn't have a key in the hash.

I want an array that has only the ones that don't have keys in the hash.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = ["MPA5534285", "MPA5534555", "MPA553asdf5", "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5"]

h = {"MPA5534555"=>"something", "MPA553sf"=>"something", "MPA55345asdf5adfads"=>"something", "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5"=>"something"} 


a - h.keys
# => ["MPA5534285", "MPA553asdf5"]
```

Answer (score 5):

This variant is a little bit faster than `a - h.keys` (it's done behind the scene when subtracting arrays anyway, only in this case rehashing of `h.keys` is not nesessary):

```
a.reject{ |e| h.has_key?(e) }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always interesting to see how solutions compare speedwise:

```
require 'benchmark'

my_array = ["MPA5534285", "MPA5534555", "MPA553asdf5", "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5"]
hash = {
  "MPA5534555"           => "something",
  "MPA553sf"             => "something",
  "MPA55345asdf5adfads"  => "something",
  "MPA553asdasdfasdfaf5" => "something"
}

n = 1_000_000

puts "For #{ n } loops:"
3.times do
  Benchmark.bm(8) do |b|
    b.report('keys')     { n.times { my_array - hash.keys                    } }
    b.report('has_key?') { n.times { my_array.reject{ |e| hash.has_key?(e) } } }
  end
end
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
ruby ~/Desktop/test.rb 
For 1000000 loops:
              user     system      total        real
keys      3.910000   0.000000   3.910000 (  3.908089)
has_key?  2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.590154)
              user     system      total        real
keys      3.930000   0.010000   3.940000 (  3.934498)
has_key?  2.580000   0.000000   2.580000 (  2.583171)
              user     system      total        real
keys      3.940000   0.000000   3.940000 (  3.936036)
has_key?  2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.589483)
```